# Add data to array on a specific place with condition

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

I have searched the web for several hours now, but can not find a decent solution.

This the case:

I want to add some data to specific arrays where the ID equals some var.

This is the data that needs to be added:

```
$var1 = "some data";
$var2 = "some other data";
```

An example of the array:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=9)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'title' => string 'title' (length=13)
      'description' => string 'Some Description' (length=21)
      'function' => string 'Some function' (length=23)
      'employment' => string 'Some employment' (length=18)
      'region' => string 'Eindhoven' (length=9)
      'region_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'function_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'employment_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=9)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'title' => string 'title2' (length=13)
      'description' => string 'Some Description2' (length=21)
      'function' => string 'Some function2' (length=23)
      'employment' => string 'Some employment2' (length=18)
      'region' => string 'Eindhoven' (length=9)
      'region_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'function_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'employment_id' => string '3' (length=1)
```

In another variable I have the id's. The condition would be something like:

```
If ($someid == $array[0][0]['id]) {
// Add 'ImNewData' => $var1;
}
```

In this example I used 2 arrays but it could be 200 in the final design.

What is the most decent (fast?) solution to do this?

Comment: As in 200 arrays deep as in scoped inside each other? If that is the case then you need a recursive function that takes an array as an argument and works through the arrays to find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best I can tell, it's sounding like you're just trying to add new data onto the array.

```
foreach ($array as $index => $user) {
    if ($user['id'] == $id) {
        $user[$index]['example_var'] = $someVar;
    }
}
```

What this does, is iterates over each element withing array[0], and stores that elements index in $index. This allows you to place those values inside of the original array. The $user value will fall out of scope after the foreach loop terminates, so you'll have to add it directly to the original array.

Comment: I think this is the answer! I got lost in php by using things as array_push(). Going to try it now.

Comment: You would only want to use array push if you were adding a new user to the end of the array, rather than modifying an existing one.

Comment: The guy before you deleted his answer. But actually he was right. I rewrote your answer: foreach ($array as $index => $user) {
    if ($user['id'] == $id) {
        $array[$index]['example_var'] = $someVar;
    }
}

Comment: Oh dear, I misread your question, I thought you had a multidimensional array :( I read it as array([0] => array([0] => 'stuff', [1] => 'stuff')